# How to change a function accepted arguments after creating it on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Or, in other words, how to make this work:

```
function foo(){}
//do something that modifies foo as if it was defined with "function foo(a,b,c){};"
console.log(foo.length); 
//output: 3
```

Comment: Function declarations don't end with a semi-colon.

Comment: Functions are immutable.

Comment: Does the function body use the arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`. If not, what's the point of defining them? If yes, why didn't it specify them in the first place?

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser, or Node.JS?  Node's got a package for some fake inheritance that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but maybe not very nice:

```
function lengthDecorator(fun) {
    function update(len) {
        var args = []; // array of parameter names
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            args.push('a' + i);
        }

        var result = new Function('fun',
            'return function(' + args.join(',') + ') {' +
                'var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);' +
                'return fun.apply(this, args);' + // call supplied function
            '}'
        ); // create a function that will return a function

        result = result(fun); // make the fun param known to the inner function
        result.update = update;
        return result;
    }
    return update(fun.length);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var foo = lengthDecorator(function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
});

print('foo.length: ' + foo.length);
print('foo(2, 3): ' + foo(2, 3));

print('');
foo = foo.update(42);
print('foo.length: ' + foo.length);
print('foo(2, 3): ' + foo(2, 3));
```

Output:

```
foo.length: 2
foo(2, 3): 5

foo.length: 42
foo(2, 3): 5
```

(Live demo: [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0th5v), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfwS7/1/))

`lengthDecorator` wraps the supplied function with a function that takes the same amount of parameters as the supplied function. The parameter count can be changed with `update`.

C.f.

- [`new Function(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function): Dynamically create a new function.
- [`fun.apply(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply): "Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array."

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {}
alert(foo.length); // 0

foo = function (a, b, c) {}
alert(foo.length); // 3
```

Comment: The question implies that the function body should *not* be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, but you can store the old `foo` in var and then redefine `foo`.

```
function foo() {...}

var oldfoo = foo;
foo = function (a, b, c) {
    oldfoo();
}
```

But what's the point?

Comment: This won't work (because I don't know the length before running the code). I'm trying to write a decorator but I'm having trouble with the fact the function returned by it is reporting a wrong value for function.length

Comment: @Dokkat perhaps you could share more of your code? It's hard to know what exactly you're doing or why the `foo.length` value would matter at all.

Answer (score -1):

The `length` property of a function object is non-writable and non-configurable, so there is no way to change its value.

You could define a new function which invokes the original function internally...